# Can I disable/enable the OK button in numeric keyboard?

Tags: android-keypad, android-input-method, android-input-filter

To enter a 6 digit pin I display the numric keyboard with OK/Enter button.

I would like to disable the OK button on the keyboard 5 or less digits were entered, so that OK is not tapable.
Only after the 6th digit was entered, the OK button shall be enabled and tapable.

Is that possible?